# Remove one "folder" from URL with a 301 redirect, keep both URLs working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My site URL: http://example.com/website/pages/home

Wanted URL: http://example.com/pages/home

I need this to be a 301 redirect so that search engines update my links.

This is what I got so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine on
\# remove /website/
RedirectMatch  ^(.+)(/website/)(.+)$ $1/$3 [L]
\# remove index.php from URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php^)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
\# deny access to wget user agent
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} wget [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [L]
```

What happens with this rules:

**Inserted URL**: http://example.com/website/pages/home

**Redirected URL**: http://example.com/index.php/pages/home

**Expected results**: http://example.com/pages/home

Thanks in advance for your help.

****SOLVED****

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine on

# remove /website/
RedirectMatch  ^(.+)(index.php/website/)(.+)$ $1$3 [R=301,L]

# remove index.php from URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php^)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# deny access to wget user agent
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} wget [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

what if you remove index.php from this line? I think this line inserts index.php into your URL.

Comment: I need the index.php to be there but not visible to the user, so my PHP scripts are interpreted correctly, hence the usage of RewriteRule, if I understood Apache documentation correctly.

Comment: you expected the URL without index.php, but you need it; could you clarify your problem?

Comment: Ok I've solve it, check OP. As for index.php I need that apache adds it internally so my PHP scripts are invocated. Sorry a can't explain this better, my English sucks :(